# Is it possible to upload big data on Google Storage using PUT method?

Tags: http, post, google-cloud-storage, put

I'm making a PUT request in order to upload data on Google Storage. But I'd like to upload big data, files around 2GB or so and I'd like to make a multi-part request. I mean, to upload an object in smaller parts and my application doesn't do it so far...Does anyone know if this is possible by using PUT method? As I saw on Google Cloud's documentation, they use POST method: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

But I'd like to use PUT method instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Storage's XML API allows uploading objects via a PUT request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object). You can use [object composition](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-compose) to upload a file in smaller parts and then join them together.

Comment: Would the Resumable Upload described on the documentation's link above have the same effect as Object Composition? I mean, it would upload my objects safely too, right? Object Composition needs a generation number and a library is needed. Perhaps it is faster and easier to implement a POST method in this case, because I would have to implement CRC32C for integrity checking for PUT method in Lua (programming language that I'm using) and it could be a waste of time...

Comment: Object composition and resumable uploads have different advantages and disadvantages. Object composition allows parallel uploads, but resumable upload have a nicer API. I believe setting the crc32c is optional (but its needed for end-to-end integrity) as is specifying generation nunmbers (although they allow you to prevent certain race conditions). I'm kinda surprised there isn't an existing crc32c library for lua though.